# Run application in background Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm developing a Cordova application that sends data (registration and image) for external server, it is already working but would like to make it if the user has no internet at registration, the application is running in background waiting for internet connection to send data, how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugin

```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

and cal your code in this callback function

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

function onOnline() {
// Handle the online event
 }
```

It will automatically run your code when internet will available

other way is to implement background service but this is simple and nice way

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

Comment: Cool, but I need that even if the application is minimized or closed, it will still send the information to my server, how do this?
I would have to work the same as DropBox

Comment: Than you have to implement background service have a look https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service

Comment: And if you want to use third party service than check this https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode