# Run a part of application in background using cordova android

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on a cordova android app.
My Question is:
is it possible to run a part of my app in background, so that the user can continue his work while sending data to server in background.

i dont want my user to wait while i sync my local database with remote database.

I dont want my whole application to go background. I want only the sync process to work in background.The total sync process is taking 3 Minutes time to complete. currently i am showing  a popup with message Sync is in progress which forces the user to wait for completion. Now i want the sync process to work in background without disturbing the user.

i used https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode but this is working when my whole application is going in background. If there is a way to solve my problem using this plugin please post here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this Question is already asked see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037529/run-application-in-background-cordova/30039245#30039245

Comment: i saw the post but the solution is not appropriate for my problem @MinahilHameed . if you know the solution please answer here.

Comment: show what you did so far